# Is "to be understood" or "to understand" correct?

Tags: grammar

There are two sentences:

> This math puzzle is very easy **to be understood**
>
> This math puzzle is very easy **to understand**

Which is more natural? Are both correct?

Comment: No.  Use *... easy to understand.*

Comment: Or 'easily understood' for a more natural language flow.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is correct:

> This math puzzle is very easy to understand.

You could also say:

> This math puzzle is very easily understood.